# Most succinct regex check in Ruby, with captures and index

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to use

```
if "a string" =~ /(.*)a (.*)/
  # do something with with $1 and $2
end
```

**and** get the index of the match.  `=~` is supposed to return the index, but I can't see a way to do that without making it messy, as in:

```
if index = ("a string" =~ /(.*)a (.*)/) # this is awful
  # would I be able to access $1 and $2 in here?
end

if match = /(.*)a (.*)/.match("a string")
  # access captures via the captures array, but that's gross
  # also, I'd have to manually find the index of the substring
end
```

So is there a trick I'm not able to Google?  Also, I'd like to maintain some performance, so I'm not open to searching for indices of the substrings via `map` or some of the other answers I've seen.

Comment: To clarify, in your particular example, you want to elegantly get the part before `"a "` and after it along with indexes? Like `{0 => "", 1 => "string"}` ?

Comment: Maybe I came up with a bad example regex, but yes... kinda. I'd be fine with just the index of the start of the match, as `=~` returns that by default... it just seems that wrapping `=~` in an `if` tosses the index.

Comment: Instead of "yes... kinda", how about defining exactly what you are trying to do, and what you want back as a result? Otherwise we're going to have to fish around and guess what you want, which is a waste of our time. Are you interested in substring matches for the "a", or do you only want complete words?

Comment: I described exactly what I wanted after that statement: I want the index that `=~` returns AND access to the captures inside the `if` block.  I also said I want the index of the match in the question.

Comment: Why not just `index =...; if index...<ref $1 and $2> end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right and that there isn't any trick that you're missing.

With `=~` you get the index but you don't get the string that is matched. At the found index you'll obviously only get one character back, which isn't what you want at all.

```
# For other readers:

string = "a string"
regexp = /a str/
index = (string =~ regexp)
string[index] #=> 'a' and not 'a str'
```

With `match` you can indeed get the exact matches but in this case you won't automatically have the index of those captures in the main string. But **at least** you have the option of manually fetching the index of each captured sub-string.

```
captured_strings.each_with_object({}) do |substring, hash|
  index = string.index(substring)
  hash[index] = substring
end

# note that finding index like that might not always work accurately
```

The way I see it, `match` is the only option here.

Comment: Your `regexp` can match things like "kinda strong". Is that what you intend? And, better, is that what the OP wants? Without that information it's really difficult to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's alright, I was just providing an example. And the OP provided just an example as well, that's not the exact code he requires. Established this in the question's comments.

Comment: `string.index(substring)` will not necessarily work, for a couple of reasons. Firstly, what if two substrings are the same? You'll get the index for the first for both. Secondly, it does not make use of the regex. Suppose, for example, the regex were `/\bcat\b/`, where `\b` forces a word boundary. `string.index('cat')` might give you the index for the start of `'catsup'` if that word preceded the word `'cat'`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I realize that. And by the nature of the OP's post, I'm guessing he is experienced enough to realize this as well. Whether or not modifications should be made in the code will depend on what kind of a string and regexp the OP has. But I agree that this is a good point to highlight. So I've made a slight edit to the answer.